# Laravel 4 auth login fails after ftp upload

Tags: laravel-4

I have been working on a website on my local pc.
I made an admin area where users have to login.

I uploaded the project to a shared hosting using ftp and copied the database.
Everything should be exactly the same, but login keeps failing.

Database is connected and the website works, I just cant get to the admin area.

In app/config/session.php the domain setting is null.
All others settings (except for DB connection) are exactly the same.

Is there something I missed here?

Comment: Have you checked the app/storage permissions in shared hosting? It must be writable by the web server?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't solve it. I found out it had to do with the php version. It was set to <5.3 or something, I set it to 5.5 and now it runs smoothly.